# CryptoJS.AES.decrypt failure reasons?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

The `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` function is returning an empty WordArray.

My parameters are `secret`, `key`, and `iv`.  key is a 256 bit WordArray and is confirmed to be correct, iv is a 128 bit WordArray and also confirmed to be correct.

secret is encrypted using php's `openssl_encrypt()` - the plaintext is 32 bytes - the result is 48 bytes (so it seems to be padding correctly).

I've tried secret as a WordArray, Hex string and base64 string but when I call:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(secret, key, {iv: iv});
```

decrypted is an empty WordArray.  It's driving me mad... What is failing?  I would think the error is in secret somewhere, with padding formats or something weird, but `Cryptojs` and o`penssl_(encrypt/decrypt)` have proved to be compatible with each other for me before.  Please help before I lose my mind.

Comment: Not familiar with either API, but WordArray might imply endianness issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so the key to this was that the docs for `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, key, {iv:iv})` say that you can feed a WordArray, Hex, or Base64 for the `message` argument.  This doesn't seem to be true.

The only way I can get it to work was by giving it a Base64 string to work with.

key and iv must still be `WordArray`

*When I tried Base64 strings in my hours of monkeying, I must not have changed the output on the server to actually send Base64 - so there you go.

Thanks to @CodesInChaos for bringing up endianess, though.  It started me messing with the encodings again.

...Now to clean up all those `console.log()`'s and `var_dump()`'s strewn about the code...

Comment: I kept feeding it a WordArray as message and I spent ages trying to figure it out. Feeding it just the Base64 immediately solved it. Thank you!

Comment: After running into this myself, I've opened as https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=112